# Parse prometheus metrics data to add label and re-parse to prometheus metrics format

Tags: parsing, go, prometheus

In short, I'm writing a program to collect some kubelets metrics remotely.

But these metrics doesn't contain information about node_name so it will duplicate when prometheus scraps it

So I want to parse their metrics, add the node name label to them, then re-parse them into prometheus metrics so I can host as an endpoint to let prometheus scraps from it

But I met problems in parsing metrics

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    dto "github.com/prometheus/client_model/go"
    "github.com/prometheus/common/expfmt"
)

func fatal(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func parseMF(path string) (map[string]*dto.MetricFamily, error) {
    reader, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var parser expfmt.TextParser
    mf, err := parser.TextToMetricFamilies(reader)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return mf, nil
}

func main() {
    f := flag.String("f", "", "set filepath")
    flag.Parse()

    mf, err := parseMF(*f)
    fatal(err)

    for k, v := range mf {
        fmt.Println("KEY: ", k)
        fmt.Println("VAL: ", v)
    }
}
```

With this simple metrics like this:

```
# HELP net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total
# TYPE net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total untyped
net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total{dialer_name="federate",instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus"} 1 1608520832877
```

the result:

```
name:"net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total" type:UNTYPED metric:<label:<name:"dialer_name" value:"federate" > label:<name:"instance" value:"localhost:9090" > label:<name:"job" value:"prometheus" > untyped:<value:1 > timestamp_ms:1608520832877 >
```

I just want to take out the name,labels,value and timestamp but I can't take it out to process, unlike python

```
from prometheus_client.parser import text_string_to_metric_families
import requests

metrics = """
# HELP net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total
# TYPE net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total untyped
net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total{dialer_name="federate",instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus"} 1 1608520832877
"""

for family in text_string_to_metric_families(metrics):
  for sample in family.samples:
    print("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{4}".format(*sample))
```

Python result:

```
net_conntrack_dialer_conn_attempted_total
{'dialer_name': 'federate', 'instance': 'localhost:9090', 'job': 'prometheus'}
1.0
1608520832.877
```

So back to the main question: How can I take out those specific value and modify it?

Comment: This is typically done by [relabeling](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config). Consider this option before writing a proxy.

Comment: That being said, what do you mean by "I can't take it out to process"? What's stopping you?

Comment: @leminhquan The code that you've posted here was written by me on a different question here on SO. I gave an idea to the OP how they can parse it; but I expect the users to do initial research of the package itself. It seems that you haven't done any research yet of our own because you have just copied the code from there and pasted the exact code here. Please read the documentation of the package used and let us know if you're stuck even after that.
Hint? Try:
`fmt.Printf("KEY: %+v\n", k)`
`fmt.Printf("VAL: %+v\n", v)`